# Windows Desktop application - Block uninstall based on bool value - C#

Tags: c#, windows, desktop

I have developed an desktop application which contains MSI build. Can we block the application based on bool value from being uninstalled by the user? I tried but it is getting uninstalled.

C# code that blocks the windows desktop application being uninstalled.

Comment: A bool where? There is IT software for software distribution that can do that. There is no reason the author of a software should be able to control that.

Comment: Bool that needs to be sent from an API. It is an monitoring application for schools. So this needs to be done from the Admin portal.

Comment: School Computers should be in Kiosk mode anyway. It's the IT dept.'s Job to ensure mandatory Software is installed and running.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Fildor. Finally, I found that there is no way to block the application uninstall process. But, I have found a way to hide the application so that the school students, they will not be able to uninstall the software. This helps us in blocking the student from uninstalling with admin privileges for them.

Comment: Let me put it this way: If a student obtains admin privileges, you have a whole different level of problems :D

Comment: Yep, absolutely. I have analyzed myself and came to a conclusion for these process. I have spoke with the admin team and restricted access via administrator. Thanks for all the ideas and support.